# netx.js cant import Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Why next.js cant import component. valid component/
i dont now how to fix this error

```
import React from "react";
import Title from '../../../common/components/Title'


export default function Fill(props: any) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Title></Title>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Title.js

```
export default function Title(props) {
  return <h1>{ props?.title }</h1>
}
```

Error when import component

```
error - ../../common/components/Title.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| export default function Title(props) {
>   return <h1>{ props?.title }</h1>
| }
|
```

Comment: could you show your `package.json` ?

Comment: {
      "name": "nextjs-front-office",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev ./prob/public",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "next": "10.2.3",
        "nextjs-webpack-override": "^1.0.1",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^15.6.1",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.7",
        "typescript": "^4.2.4"
      }
    }

Comment: add package.json

Comment: Try to add `import React from "react";` to `Title.js` at the top.

Comment: add react import. dont work

Comment: Describe your folder structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve path from parent folder

next.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  webpack: function (config, { defaultLoaders }) {
    const resolvedBaseUrl = path.resolve(config.context, "../../");
    config.module.rules = [
      ...config.module.rules,
      {
        test: /\.(tsx|ts|js|mjs|jsx)$/,
        include: [resolvedBaseUrl],
        use: defaultLoaders.babel,
        exclude: (excludePath) => {
          return /node_modules/.test(excludePath);
        },
      },
    ];
    return config;
  }
};
```